# Conditionally change GetHashCode() when comparing two objects

Tags: c#, .net, performance, comparison, gethashcode

I have two different lists of objects and want to get their similarities, based on the weight of some of the properties. Quickest way seems to be with implementing an IEquatable interface and that is what have I done:

```
public class CompareEntry : IEquatable<CompareEntry>
{
    public int LeadId { get; set; }
    public int SaleId { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string PhonePrivate { get; set; }
    public string PhoneMobile { get; set; }
    public string PhoneCompany { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }

    public bool Equals(CompareEntry other)
    {
        int weight = 0;

        //Check whether the compared object is null.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(other, null))
        {
            return false;
        }

        //Check whether the compared object references the same data.
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(this, other))
        {
            return true;
        }

        if ((this.CheckProperties(this.Email, other.Email) && this.Email == other.Email)
           || (this.CheckProperties(this.PhonePrivate, other.PhonePrivate) && this.PhonePrivate == other.PhonePrivate)
           || (this.CheckProperties(this.PhoneMobile, other.PhoneMobile) && this.PhoneMobile == other.PhoneMobile)
           || (this.CheckProperties(this.PhoneCompany, other.PhoneCompany) && this.PhoneCompany == other.PhoneCompany))
        {
            weight += 100;
        }

        if ((this.CheckProperties(this.Name, other.Name) && this.Name == other.Name)
            || (this.CheckProperties(this.FirstName, other.FirstName) && this.FirstName == other.FirstName))
        {
            weight += 25;
        }

        if ((this.CheckProperties(this.City, other.City) && this.City == other.City)
            || (this.CheckProperties(this.ZipCode, other.ZipCode) && this.ZipCode == other.ZipCode))
        {
            weight += 12;
        }

        if (this.CheckProperties(this.CompanyName, other.CompanyName) && this.CompanyName == other.CompanyName)
        {
            weight += 5;
        }

        return weight > 50;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = (int)2166136261;

            hash = hash * 16777619 ^ (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Email) ? 0 : Email.GetHashCode());
            //hash = hash * 16777619 ^ (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhonePrivate) ? 0 : PhonePrivate.GetHashCode());
            //hash = hash * 16777619 ^ (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneMobile) ? 0 : PhoneMobile.GetHashCode());
            //hash = hash * 16777619 ^ (string.IsNullOrEmpty(PhoneCompany) ? 0 : PhoneCompany.GetHashCode());
            //hash = hash * 16777619 ^ (string.IsNullOrEmpty(FirstName) ? 0 : FirstName.GetHashCode());
            //hash = hash * 16777619 ^ (string.IsNullOrEmpty(Name) ? 0 : Name.GetHashCode());
            //hash = hash * 16777619 ^ (string.IsNullOrEmpty(City) ? 0 : City.GetHashCode());
            //hash = hash * 16777619 ^ (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ZipCode) ? 0 : ZipCode.GetHashCode());
            //hash = hash * 16777619 ^ (string.IsNullOrEmpty(CompanyName) ? 0 : CompanyName.GetHashCode());

            return hash;
        }
    }

    private bool CheckProperties(string prop, string otherProp)
    {
        return !string.IsNullOrEmpty(prop) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(otherProp);
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I override GetHashCode() method I only get those who are fully same or in this particular case - only with same Email.

How can I also conditionally check weight in GetHashCode() method, so that I could use correct the method Equals?
Or is there a way to do the similarities check with some other way, which is performance good?

Comment: A correct implementation of `Equals` has to have the property that if A equals B and B equals C then A equals C. I am not sure that your `Equals` implementation has that property. And when an implementation lacks that property you will often struggle with creating a correct implementation of  `GetHashCode` which is exactly what you experience.

Comment: You really shouldn't be overriding `Equals()` to do fuzzy matching, it breaks all sorts of contracts such as [transitivity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_relation) when passed to a `Sort()` method.

Comment: Why can't you compute weight of the object in a separate method and then use the output of that method in GetHashCode()?
But note that GetHashCode is not intended to compare objects for equality, it just gives a hint to hashing algorithms in Dictionary and alike implementations to distribute objects in the hash table

Comment: @Phylogenesis: Equality isn't useful for sorting anyway - there's a big difference between `IComparable` and `IEquatable`. I agree that fuzzy matching is a bad fit for equality, but sorting is a red herring.

Comment: @JonSkeet True. It was a bad example.

Comment: @DenisYarkovoy: I believe the problem here is to create an implementation of `GetHashCode` that has the required property that if two objects are equal they have to return the same value from `GetHashCode`. And because equality has been defined in a "fuzzy way" you can' really come up with a good algorithm for `GetHashCode` except simply returning a constant value.

Comment: Thank you all for the fast responses. I gave up this solution and will think of something else.

Comment: Please never never never compute `GetHashCode` using the values from mutable properties/fields. It is important for `GetHashCode` to remain the same throughout the lifetime of the object so that it can be used in dictionaries and any other hash-based data structures.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Equals` / `GetHashCode` aren't designed to compare things which are "mostly equal". Equality is just a Boolean property in this case. In particular, having a fuzzy "mostly equal" approach leads to problems with transitivity. The documentaiton of [`Object.Equals`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bsc2ak47) includes this requirment:

> If `(x.Equals(y) && y.Equals(z))` returns `true`, then `x.Equals(z)` returns `true`.

That simply doesn't hold when you have fuzzy equality. Just because `x` is "quite like" `y` and `y` is "quite like" `z` doesn't mean that `x` is "quite like" `z`.

Now what you *can* do is have an equality comparer which only compares phone numbers, another equality comparer which only compares names, etc - but that won't really get you fuzzy matching.